# Is there an equivalent to Android's Activity Recognition API in iOS?

Tags: ios, accelerometer, activity-recognition

On the last Google I/O was introduced a new service in the Location API's in Android - Activity Recognition.

Is there such a framework for iOS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I realize this question is old, but for future reference [CMMotionActivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivity_class/Reference/Reference.html) provides this functionality.  New to iOS 7 and enabled by the M7 coprocessor.

Comment: CMMotionActivityManager would be a more reference look at.